# How do I make a uppercase letter only in ruby?

Tags: ruby, terminal, ide

so this is my method right now.

```
:christmas => ["Lights", "Wreath"],
:new_years => ["Party Hats"]
```

and i have this to get "christmas:": and that passes my IDE now

```
puts  "  #{key_holiday.to_s.split("_").join(" ").capitalize}: #{supplies.join(", ")}"
```

now the IDE is asking for

```
expected: ("  New Years: Party Hats")
got :     ("  New year: Party Hats")
```

can someone help me capitalize the "Y" in years thats the only error I have right now thanks.

Comment: @Alter Lagos will do , thanks.

Comment: I see 2 differences: you have `year` vs. `Years` – the latter is uppercase and plural, i.e. with a trailing `s`.

Answer (score 1):

```
key_holiday.to_s.split("_").map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
```

since you want to capitalize each word, use `map` to modify the array `["new", "year"]` to `["New", "Year"]` then join the words with a space.

Answer (score 1):

On top of Yoav Epstein's comment,

if you are trying to get the mentioned functionality on Rails, you can use `titleize` function.

```
pry(main)> "new year: Party HATS".titleize
=> "New Year: Party Hats"
```

Answer (score 0):

`.upcase` instead of `.capitalize` should get you caps capitalize only uppercases the first character, upcase will get the whole thing

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-string-capitalize-method/